# Dynamic DB login in TYPO3 extension

Tags: php, mysql, export, typo3

So I want to build an extension, where you can export the data via php to excel or something similar. Since I'm planning to distribute it, until now not sure if public or just to my close web-dev-friends, it wouldn't be a good idea to connect to the DB by typing in my credentials directly.

Is there a way to import them from the LocalConfiguration.php file? In this way, it will also always work on other installations of T3.

Another or even a better way would be the T3-API, were I did only understand train-station (German proverb). T3-API sounds like C3-POs best friend, though.

You might have noticed that I'm quite new to php and file-generation is maybe a little big task to set oneself. But without challenge, it wouldn't be fun, right?

**Environment:** TYPO3 7.4.0 // MySQL 5.5.46 // PHP Version 5.6.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the TYPO3 database connection, which is available in the variable `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']` (not sure if there is a better way in newer TYPO3 versions). This connection is automatically created from the database info in `LocalConfiguration.php`.

The variable is of type `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\DatabaseConnection`, the API documentation can be found [here](http://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_database_1_1_database_connection.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried out `$result = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTquery('*', 'tx_berichtsheft_domain_model_woche', 'deleted=0');` and `print $result` but it returns an Internal Server Error (500). Any idea?

Comment: Enable the development mode (in the install tool, under preset configurations), and check the error message. Don't forget to switch back to production mode later. Also check the PHP error log and the web servers error log.

Comment: I think it's because it's just a .php-file implemented by an iFrame inside the action-template of the ext. Where do I have to write the code to make it valid?

Comment: Oh, ok - you should write your code inside the action, or even better, put it into some service class, and inject an instance of that class into your controller. Also, if you are using extbase, you could use an extbase repository to retrieve the data from the database instead of brewing your own stuff using `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']`.

Comment: Wow, I guess there will be a lot to read. But thanks, this sounds like the correct answer, now at least I know what to google. I'll give you a green checkmark.

Comment: @Norman, you should start at the documentation, especially at ``Developing TYPO3 CMS Extensions with Extbase and Fluid`` available as part of the official documentation at https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/ or for sale as german version.